# Set image source to null if no image is present

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, file-upload

I am using [Krajee FileInput System](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo).I have a form which allows the user to upload photo but its not mandatory.The problem is that at the time of editing the form if no files are uploaded im getting the following exception.

```
Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: contentPath
```

How can I modify the code to accept if the image is null??

The code I have tried

```
 $(function () {
        var getCaption = function (imgUrl) {
            if (imgUrl != null) {
                var dataArray = imgUrl.split("/");
                var caption = dataArray[dataArray.length - 1];
                return caption
            }               
        }          

        //fileUpload plugin
        $("#txtPhoto").fileinput({
            showUpload: false,
            initialPreview: [
                '<img src="@Url.Content(Model.StudentRegistration.PhotoUrl!=null?Model.StudentRegistration.PhotoUrl:"")" class="file-preview-image" alt="' + getCaption("@Model.StudentRegistration.PhotoUrl") + '" title="' + getCaption("@Model.StudentRegistration.PhotoUrl") + '">'
            ],
            overwriteInitial: true,
            initialCaption: getCaption("@Model.StudentRegistration.PhotoUrl")
        });
    });
```

Comment: On which line do you get this exception?

Comment: The exception is in the line img src tag

Comment: Did you try it without the call to `@Url.Content`?

Comment: Nope..Will try that too.

Comment: @RowlandShaw now the exception is gone,but image content is still showing.Any way to make the plugin not show the image

Answer (score 0):

can you try like this

```
 initialPreview: [
              @if (Model.StudentRegistration.PhotoUrl != null)
             {
                '<img src="@Model.StudentRegistration.PhotoUrl)" class="file-preview-image" alt="' + getCaption(" @Model.StudentRegistration.PhotoUrl ") + '" title="' + getCaption(" @Model.StudentRegistration.PhotoUrl ") + '">'
             }
         ],
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.tried that but getting the error `too many characters in character literal`